# What would cause virtual hosts to use the same version of php-fpm after adding distinct fpm handlers?

Tags: virtualhost, php-fpm, apache2

As soon as I enable php8.1-fpm.conf, all my sites switch from using php7.4-fpm to php8.1-fpm. All my vhost files have fpm handlers added to the `<VirtualHost *:80>` blocks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org
  ServerName www.somesite.info
  # Only if there will be a temporary subdomain:
  DocumentRoot /srv/www/somesite.info/web/
  ErrorLog /srv/www/somesite.info/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /srv/www/somesite.info/logs/access.log combined
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.somesite.info
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
  </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>

# Handle all other domains/subdomains
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName somesite.info
  Redirect 301 / http://www.somesite.info/
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =somesite.info
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

for each php-fpm, I'm using 7.4 and 8.1. I'm looking for clues to track down where my config error could be, I've enabled the necessary modules are per [this documentation](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/install-php-8-for-apache-and-nginx-on-ubuntu/#install-and-configure-php-fpm).

Comment: Most probably something in the config you are not showing.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I've added the rest of the file for context, although my thought is that the configuration error is someplace else.